# vertical-align wrapper div won't work with multiple lines of text

Tags: html, css

I can't vertically align (middle) a div with 2 lines of text. One line, yes, but not 2. I'd like one of the lines to be like a h2, the other like a paragraph. I realize I could achieve a "h2" and "p" look with styling, but I can't put them on separate lines.

https://jsfiddle.net/aaunr9wr/4/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-g-300-200-9.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="text-wrapper">
        <h2>Middle</h2>
        <p>How is this aligned?</p>
    </div>
</div>

.wrapper{
  border:1px solid #f00;
  width:90%;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:1em;
}
.image-wrapper{
  display:inline;
  margin-right:1em;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.text-wrapper{
  vertical-align:middle;
  display:inline;
}
.text-wrapper p{
  display:inline;
}
.text-wrapper h2{
  display:inline;
}
img{
 vertical-align:middle;
}
h2,p{
  margin:0;
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: How about something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/aaunr9wr/6/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `inline` from `p` and `h2`, then set the `display:inline-block` for`.text-wrapper`: https://jsfiddle.net/ilpo/aaunr9wr/5/

Edit: the reason it doesn't work with multiple lines is that its max-width is by default 100%. So as you insert more text, the `.text-wrapper` no longer fits on the same text line as the image. You can resolve this by setting a `max-width`. Your `max-width` should be at most whatever is left over from the space the `image` takes up:

https://jsfiddle.net/ilpo/aaunr9wr/7/

Comment: This sorta works. But not really. If the text needs to wrap, then it falls apart.

Comment: Does it now have the expected behaviour?

Comment: Yes, it does. I am shocked and awed! Thank you.

Comment: The one thing that is a problem is that browser support for calc() is not quite there yet. (Android, Opera) But I was able to take your solution and after setting max-width to a percentage, it worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use these styles on `.image-wrapper` and `.text-wrapper`:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
```

Remove your existing styles from `.text-wrapper p` and `.text-wrapper h2`.

**Complete CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
  border:1px solid #f00;
  width:90%;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:1em;
}
.image-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
.text-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
h2, p {
  margin:0;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/snqywdnw/)

Comment: I do NOT want the h2 and the p side by side. Ilpo almost had it, but the paragraph needs to be able to wrap. in his example, when the text is long enough to wrap, then the layout breaks.